# Flink runner not splitting tasks when parallelism is turned on in BEAM python pipeline

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I have a beam pipeline written in python that when deployed to a flink runner doesn't make use of the parallelism correctly.

There is unbounded data coming in through a kafka connector and I want the data to be read when split in parallel.

My understanding is that it should split up the tasks but as shown in the image one parallelism is used and all the other 5 sub tasks finished instantly leaving the one running to do all the work.

The pipeline settings are:

```
options = PipelineOptions([
 "--runner=PortableRunner",
 "--sdk_worker_parallelism=3",
 "--artifact_endpoint=localhost:8098",
 "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099",
 "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
 "--environment_config=localhost:50000",
 "--checkpointing_interval=30000",
])
options._all_options['parallelism'] = 3
```

[image]

Is this a missing config on the Flink runner or something that can be configured in the BEAM pipeline?

The full pipeline:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
options = PipelineOptions([
    "--runner=PortableRunner",
    "--sdk_worker_parallelism=3",
    "--artifact_endpoint=localhost:8098",
    "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099",
    "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
    "--environment_config=localhost:50000",
    "--checkpointing_interval=30000",
])

options._all_options['parallelism'] = 3

class CountProvider(beam.RestrictionProvider):
  def __init__(self, initial_split_size=5):
    self._initial_split_size = initial_split_size
    self.OffsetRestrictionTracker = None
  def imports(self):
    if self.OffsetRestrictionTracker is not None: return
    from apache_beam.io.restriction_trackers import OffsetRestrictionTracker, OffsetRange
    self.OffsetRestrictionTracker = OffsetRestrictionTracker
    self.OffsetRange = OffsetRange
  def initial_restriction(self, element):
    self.imports()
    return self.OffsetRange(0, 10)
  def create_tracker(self, restriction):
    self.imports()
    return self.OffsetRestrictionTracker(restriction)
  def restriction_size(self, element, restriction):
      return restriction.size()*100_000
  def split(self, element, restriction):
    self.imports()
    if restriction.start + 1 >= restriction.stop:
      yield self.OffsetRange(restriction.start, restriction.stop)
    else:
      last_val = restriction.start
      for i in range(1, self._initial_split_size):
        next_stop = i * (restriction.start + restriction.stop) // self._initial_split_size
        yield self.OffsetRange(last_val, next_stop)
        last_val = next_stop
      yield self.OffsetRange(last_val, restriction.stop)

class CountFn(beam.DoFn):
  def setup(self):
    print("setup")
  def process(self, element, tracker=beam.DoFn.RestrictionParam(CountProvider())):
    res = tracker.current_restriction()
    print(f"Current Restriction {res.start}, {res.stop}")
    for i in range(res.start, res.stop):
      if not tracker.try_claim(i):
        return
      for j in range(10_000):
        yield i, j
  
  def get_initial_restriction(self, filename):
    return (0, 10)
  def teardown(self):
    print("Teardown")

p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
out = (p | f'Create' >> beam.Create([tuple()])
         | f'Gen Data' >> beam.ParDo(CountFn())
         | beam.Map(print)
)

result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```